# iOS: Memory warning makes buttons disappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, warnings, memory-leaks

I am running my iOS app on an iPod touch and I seem to receive a lot of memory warnings. Not sure why that is, I have used Instruments and I don't use that much memory. Anyway, sometimes after receiving memory warnings some of the UIBarButtonItems on the toolbar disappear (for example, the back button in a navigation controller).

That's a real problem, the only fix is to kill the app and restart. How can I handle such situations? Maybe there is a way to reload the bar button items? Has anyone encountered something comparable, how would you proceed?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I should add that my UIBarButtonItems have custom images. I set those images in viewDidLoad. Maybe the low memory warning releases those images, and then they aren't loaded ever again. I think that might be it, but how do I make sure that if the view appears again, the images are loaded again?

EDIT2: It seems like the problem is that in viewDidUnload I set one of the BarButtonItems to nil. I think that was actually automatically inserted by XCode when I set the IBOutlet. Is that the right thing to do, or should I not set it to nil. If so, how do I reassign it properly later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the images locally and there are no strong references to them, then they are viewed as "disposable" by the OS as soon as they are out of scope. When the memory warning is received they are deallocated. Try keeping a larger-scope reference to the images.

Comment: Ok, so I did some more testing and it appears that when I get a memory warning (or if I simulate it in the simulator), then my BarButtonItems are set to nil. How do I reassign them? I created them in the Storyboard, so they are IBOUtlets (strong and nonatomic).

Comment: Just to add to that, I think it's not just that the images are deallocated, it's the whole UIBarButtonItem that is deallocated.

Comment: You should implement didreceivememorywarning and release some other things you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating the symptoms (UIBarButtons disappearing), try and find where your program is leaking memory. Here are some tips on finding memory leaks:

1. Go through your code and find all instances of where you malloc and make sure you are deallocing
2. Use the profiler to find memory leaks, most times it will name the objects that aren't being dealloced properly.
3. Checkout this [presentation](http://www.streamingcolour.com/blog/2010/09/21/presentation-finding-fixing-mem-leaks/) on finding leaks.

Finally after you are sure that you aren't getting memory leaks and those warnings, but your buttons are still disappearing, post some code in a new question.

Comment: He might not be leaking memory; iPod touches often have low memory capacity. If the app was written for a higher-capacity device it could easily trigger a memory warning without any leaks.

Comment: I don't have any problems with iPhone. iPod touch does seem to have much lower memory capacity. Also, I am using ARC.

Comment: Also, those memory warnings often appear when I log in through Facebook, i.e. call the Facebook app for authentication. Not sure if I can change anything related to that.

Comment: @user1013725 In addition to Michael's great suggestions, make sure you run your code through the static analyzer (shift+command+B) and resolve any issues it reports. This is especially useful in quickly identifying the sources of simple leaks in non-ARC code. You should have absolutely no warnings from the analyzer.